# Ionic - Camera.getPicture try to close my rootPage

Tags: ionic-framework, camera

Hi guys, I try to take a photo with ionic native camera to use an OCR plugin.

```
takePhoto() {
this.camera.getPicture({
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: 0, // DATA_URL
  sourceType: 1,
  allowEdit: true,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
  correctOrientation: true
}).then((imageData) => {
  this.srcImage = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${imageData}`;
}, (err) => {
  console.log(`ERROR -> ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
});
```

}

I got almost what I expect.

My problem is that when I click on my button that trigger this function, I got an error like :

```
Uncaught (in promise): navigation stack needs at least one root page
```

I am on a rootPage and this function seems to close my rootPage ?

Thank in advance for your help !

EDIT : my function takePhoto() is trigger in my view by a button

EDIT :

```
import {Camera} from "@ionic-native/camera";
...
constructor(private camera: Camera){
}
...
takePhoto(){ ... }
```

Comment: show more code?

Comment: @AaronSaunders which part of my code you need to see ?

Comment: @AaronSaunders I found the answer. it's a mistake about a submit form function triggered.
Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer ! on my view, I got a form with a submit function that close my view, triggered at the same time that my takePhoto function.

My mistake, sorry for that.